# How to read new values only in treeview from CSV file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code here:

```
def insert_Data_Custom(self):
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as fd:
        fd.write(self.customer_entry.get() + "," +
        self.product_entry.get() + "," +
        self.weight_entry.get() + "," +
        self.in_out_entry.get() + "," +
        self.quantity_entry.get() + "," +
        self.batch_entry.get() + "," +
        self.best_before_entry.get() + '\n')
        fd.close()

    with open('data.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            customer = row['Customer']
            product = row['Product']
            weight = row['Weight']
            inner_outer = row['Inner/Outer']
            quantity = row['Quantity']
            batch = row['Batch']
            bbe = row['Best Before']
            Progress = row['Progress']
            self.progress_view.insert("", 0, values=(customer,product,weight,inner_outer,quantity,batch,bbe,Progress))


    self.customer_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.product_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.weight_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.in_out_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.quantity_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.batch_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.best_before_entry.delete(0, 'end')
```

top part gets all values and appends into csv file. Along with that, middle code will add values into treeview from csv values.

My problem is, when I click a button to activate this function, it inserts data into CSV and Treeview reads the CSV values and shows the values. But if I insert another value, treeview will duplicate previous values and add new record on.

How do I get the treeview only to append new records inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is, when I click a button to activate this function, it
>   inserts data into CSV and Treeview reads the CSV values and shows the
>   values. But if I insert another value, treeview will duplicate
>   previous values and add new record on.

You have to check if your `treeview` has any `child` and delete those `children` before you start your insert.

```
if self.progress_view.winfo_children():
    for widget in self.progress_view.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have used 
        for i in self.progress_view.get_children():
            self.progress_view.delete(i)

Comment: Sure! do you have couple minutes on chat? Just need some help using pandas